# Who are these creatures/entities - Sahajā, Kulajā, Mālā, Ḍākinī, Śhākinī (From Devī Kavacham: Durgā Saptaśhati)?

Tags: devi, durga, durga-saptasati, kavacha

The [Devī Kavacham](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/dkavach.html) (from Durgā Saptaśhati) protects us from Sahajā, Kulajā, Mālā, Ḍākinī, Śhākinī.

> **सहजा कुलजा माला डाकिनी शाकिनी** तथा।
> अन्तरिक्षचरा घोरा डाकिन्यश्‍च महाबलाः ॥ ५०॥
>
> ***Sahajā Kulajā Mālā Ḍākinī Śhākinī** Tathā* ।
> *Antarikṣacarā Ghorā Ḍākinyaśca Mahābalāḥ* ॥ 50॥

Who are these creatures / entities?

Comment: Dakini and Shakini are deities of various chakras.. Not sure about Sahaja and Kulaja though...

Comment: @Tezz- If they are deities, why does the Goddess offer protection against them?

Comment: They are not deities,apparently,I’ve posted an answer below,that states otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are **“bhoots”** ,as per [this source](https://books.google.com.qa/books?id=6T_VDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA89&lpg=PA89&dq=sahaja%20kulaja&source=bl&ots=lHBXHIKcK5&sig=ACfU3U0p01OZUf9sUZFe0v4A_nSjuffIlw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwirxv-ExvjwAhXhjOYKHZnPCkcQ6AEwBXoECAYQAg) :

Here is the relevant portion:

> [image]

The last part of the highlighted portion reads “Kavach in their heart”

Hope this helps.

Comment: Was there anything wrong?@Vivikta?

Comment: No no. Don't worry. I just tried to make it more Formatted and "aesthetic". If you'r not satisfied with my edit, you may roll-back. :)

Comment: No problem,@ Vivikta.

Comment: Thank you, this is clear @Amethyst.

Comment: @curiousseeker You’re welcome.!